# conditional check against list of strings in GNU makefile command

Tags: makefile, command, conditional-statements, gnu

I am trying to check a file against a list before I try to compile it in a GNU makefile. Will the conditional ifneq below be evaluated every time the rule is invoked or just once? The condition seems to always evaluate the same way.

If not is the only way to do this to put the conditional in the shell command? I realize it may seem weird that the target list could be "not OK" ... the Make system could certainly be fixed to eliminate that weirdness but the pain will be greater.

Any suggestions?
Eli

```
OKSRC := realfile1.cpp realfile2.cpp

%.o: %.cpp
ifneq ($(findstring $<,$(OKSRC),),)
        ... do the compile
else
        #skip the file
endif
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense.  If you don't compile the file, then `target.o` won't get created, which will break some other rule in your makefile.  What is your aim here?

Comment: It should not have been target.o, but the more generic %.o. I made the edit. You are right if it were all simple, but the build system has a flaw and some %.o are falsely identified as being required as prerequisites. These %.o can be safely ignored. The context would take paragraphs, so I have abstracted the useful part for learning about Make. I have seen the unindented "ifneq" pattern before but not one that clarifies if it is re-evaluated for every new $< and $@. If not, I suppose I need a shell solution of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [Make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles):

> Conditional directives are parsed immediately. This means, for example, that automatic variables cannot be used in conditional directives, as automatic variables are not set until the recipe for that rule is invoked. If you need to use automatic variables in a conditional directive you must move the condition into the recipe and use shell conditional syntax instead.

`ifneq` is a conditional directive, and `$<` is an automatic variable.  So in short, your above code will not work, so you would have to use the shell-based conditional.

But I would strongly suggest that you fix the root cause (i.e. the erroneous dependency generation), rather than trying to hack around it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `if` function to defer the expansion of automatic variables until the condition is evaluated.

```
OKSRC = realfile1.cpp realfile2.cpp

.cpp.o:
    $(if $(findstring $<,$(OKSRC)),$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<,@echo skip $<)
```

And the result shows:

```
$ make realfile1.o realfile2.o realfile3.o
cc  -c realfile1.cpp
cc  -c realfile2.cpp
skip realfile3.cpp
```